# PayPal API Taking Very Long Time To Respond

Tags: performance, paypal, payflowlink

I am using following PayPal API

https://payflowlink.paypal.com/

It is taking very long time. Please check following screenshot.

[image]

Is it a PayPal issue? How to improve the speed? Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

payflowlink.paypal.com is not an API, it's a hosted field application

If it's too slow try something more modern like https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , or Braintree Direct if you need a full gateway

Answer (score -1):

switch network environment or put your code from local to linux server.

Comment: It is already AWS instance and website is in production mode.

Comment: Define 'switch network environment'. Switch to what? Why? What problem will it solve? and why? And why would moving the code from local to a Linux server fix it? whatever 'it' is?